# How to convert data type varchar to timestamp mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select

I have database mysql with table 'tblevel' with column 'waktu' with varchar data type.
and the column hold values like this:

`30-01-2014 12:19:09`

The value will be converted to timestamp, because I have to do that for data viewing in graphic, in this case I use google data visualisation,

The shorted code is :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,FROM_UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(waktu, '%H:%i:%s %b %d, %Y')), now()) as waktu1,level,press FROM tblevel WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(waktu) , now()) < 120 Order By waktu");
```

hope someone help to correct the code .thanks
regards Fixduino.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.waktu, a.level, a.press 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, STR_TO_DATE(a.waktu, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'), NOW()) AS waktu1           
FROM tblevel a
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, STR_TO_DATE(a.waktu, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'), NOW()) < 120 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(a.waktu, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: @shaharsh shars : i have do your code,,but still no respon. you can look this pic [https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BfNbowECMAAfs-t.png] and [https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BfNbuhxCMAA_sJh.png]..

Answer (score 0):

The Date format  of MySQL is YMD, try this

```
SELECT a.waktu, a.level, a.press 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, STR_TO_DATE(a.waktu, '%y-%M-%d %H:%i:%s'), NOW()) AS waktu1           
FROM tblevel a
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, STR_TO_DATE(a.waktu, '%y-%M-%d %H:%i:%s'), NOW()) < 120 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(a.waktu, '%y-%M-%d %H:%i:%s');
```